# How to implement a toggle effect with react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have been searching for a  long time in google. But  I haven't found anything. I am looking for a way to  implement a toggle effect with reactjs.
Please have a look at my code below.

```
var Demo = React.createClass({
            getInitialState:function(){
                return {show:false};
            },
            onClick:function(){
                this.setState({show:true});
            },
            render: function(){
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div className="demo" onClick={this.onClick}>
                            Demo
                            {this.state.show?<Demosub />:null}
                        </div>
                        <div className="demo" onClick={this.onClick}>
                            Demo
                            {this.state.show?<Demosub />:null}
                        </div>
                        <div className="demo" onClick={this.onClick}>
                            Demo
                            {this.state.show?<Demosub />:null}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });

        var Demosub = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return (
                    <div>Demo sub</div>
                );
            }
        });
```

Comment: this.state.show represent the state for all the 3 divs with class demo?

Comment: No @elio.d. The targeted element child only will open when i click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would encapsulate each item in its own component like that:

```
var Demo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DemoItem />
        <DemoItem />
        <DemoItem />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var DemoItem = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { show: false };
  },
  toggleShow: function() {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="demo" onClick={this.toggleShow}>
        Demo
        {this.state.show ? <DemoSub /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var DemoSub = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Demo sub</div>
  }
});
```

Comment: how would you advance it, when there shall be just one `<DemoSub />` shown for multiple `<DemoItem />`s so that when I click on one of them Demo Sub box changes the content accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  

class Person extends Component {

   state={
        showPerson:false,
    }

toggleName=()=>{
    const doesShow = this.state.showPerson;
    this.setState({
        showPerson:!doesShow
    })
}

render() {

    let personList = null;
if(this.state.showPerson) {
    personList = (
        <div> Show Content </div>
    )
}
    return (
        <div>
             <button onClick={this.toggleName}>Switch</button>
             {personList}
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Person;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some description on your answer so others can understand easily.